# Https connection Android with Http authentication

Tags: java, android, android-studio, https, http-authentication

I want to make a HTTPS connection with a webservice in Android Studio but it doesn't work with the code that I have written. I get a FileNotFound Exception.

My URL is working in the browser.

And response code is 400.

This is my code:

```
 protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            String https_url = "HERE MY HTTPS URL";
            URL url;
            try {

                url = new URL(https_url);
                HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                String userPassword = "USERNAME" + ":" + "PASSWORD";
                String encoding = new String(Base64.encode(userPassword.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT));
                con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
                con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 ( compatible ) ");
                con.setRequestProperty("Accept","*/*");

                //dumpl all cert info
                print_https_cert(con);

                //dump all the content
                print_content(con);

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return null;
    }
```

Someone who can help me out?

Comment: A few things: 1) is your URL a localhost address? There could be some cross-domain issues if that's the case. 2) I'm curious about Base64.DEFAULT (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/archives/1.9/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html says it might need to be OFF for URL-safeness, even if it's a header value) 3) Your "User-Agent" header isn't really Mozilla, right? Do you actually need to specify this? 4) What headers are accepted by your web service? Normally you need to specify exactly what gets accepted, consumed, produced, etc.

Comment: I'm not working with Localhost.
The API works with Digest (example 2): http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php